# Web.config - неправильно парсится.

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmlparser, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с тем, что файл конфига (web.config) неправильно парсится.
Онлайн Валидаторы  пишут, что  ошибок нету, а при парсинге я получаю не конкретное значение элемента а комментарий, написанный над ним.

Пишу так:

```
XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration").SelectSingleNode("appSettings").SelectSingleNode("OperatorXMLAccessDisable");
```

В результате должно получиться `true/false`, а я получаю коментарий строчкой выше.

В Web.config'e:

```
<!--
Признак запрещенности простым операторам, не супервизорам, редактировать
карточку контакта.
Возможные значения:
1. true - только операторы типа "супервизор" могут редактировать карточку
2. fasle - все операторы могут редактировать карточку
-->
<add key="OperatorXMLAccessDisable" value="true" />
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо использовать ConfigurationManager: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OperatorXMLAccessDisable"];